# Notation in proof for the asymptotic equipartition property

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, notation, information-theory

In the following [lecture notes](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee376a/files/lecture_notes.pdf) chapter 3, page 12-13, they state the following

> We begin by introducting some important notation:
>   - For a set $\mathcal{S},|\mathcal{S}|$ denotes its cardinality (number of elements contained on the set). For example, let $\mathcal{U}=\{1,2, \ldots, M\},$ then $|\mathcal{U}|=M$
>   - $  u^{n}=\left(u_{1}, \ldots, u_{n}\right)$ is an $n$ -tuple of $u$
>   - $ \mathcal{U}^{n}=\left\{u^{n} | u_{i} \in \mathcal{U} ; i=1, \ldots, n\right\} .$ It is easy to see that $\left|\mathcal{U}^{n}\right|=|\mathcal{U}|^{n}$
>   - $ U_{i}$ generated by a memoryless source $U^{'}$ implies $U_{1}, U_{2}, \ldots$ i.i.d. according to $U$ (or $P_{U}$ ). That is.
>
> $$p\left(u^{n}\right)=\prod_{i=1}^{n} p\left(u_{i}\right)$$
>   **Definition** **12**. The sequence $u^{n}$ is $\epsilon$ -typical for a memoryless source U for $\epsilon>0,$ if
>   $$
> \left|-\frac{1}{n} \log p\left(u^{n}\right)-H(U)\right| \leq \epsilon
> $$
>   or equivalently,
>   $$
> 2^{-n(H(U)+\epsilon)} \leq p\left(u^{n}\right) \leq 2^{-n(H(U)-\epsilon)}
> $$
>   Let $A_{\epsilon}^{(n)}$ denote the set of all $\epsilon$ -typical sequences, called the typical set.
>   So a length- $n$ typical sequence would assume a probability approximately equal to $2^{-n H(U)}$. Note that this applies to memoryless sources, which will be the focus on this course $^{1}$.
>   **Theorem 13 (AEP)**. $\forall \epsilon>0, P\left(U^{n} \in A_{\epsilon}^{(n)}\right) \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$
>
> **Proof** This is a direct application of the Law of Large Numbers (LLN).
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> P\left(U^{n} \in A_{\epsilon}^{(n)}\right) &=P\left(\left|-\frac{1}{n} \log p\left(U^{n}\right)-H(U)\right| \leq \epsilon\right) \\
> &=P\left(\left|-\frac{1}{n} \log \prod_{i=1}^{n} p\left(U_{i}\right)-H(U)\right| \leq \epsilon\right) \\
> &=P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}-\log p\left(U_{i}\right)\right]-H(U)\right| \leq \epsilon\right) \\
> & \rightarrow 1 \text { as } n \rightarrow \infty
> \end{aligned}
> $$
>   where the last step is due to the Law of Large Numbers (LLN), in which $-\log p\left(U_{i}\right)$ 's are i.i.d. and hence their arithmetic average converges to their expectation $H(U)$

**My question** is related to the proof.
My understanding is the following; $U^n$ is a sequence of random variables $U^n = (U_1, U_2, \ldots,U_n)$ drawn i.i.d from some distribution $p_U(u) = p(u)$ and $u^n$ is a realization of the sequence.

However in the proof they switch from using $p(u^n)$ to $p(U^n)$ and I am not sure what $p(U^n)$ represents? What would be wrong by doing it as follows?

$$
\begin{aligned}
P\left(u^{n} \in A_{\epsilon}^{(n)}\right) &=P\left(\left|-\frac{1}{n} \log p\left(u^{n}\right)-H(U)\right| \leq \epsilon\right) \\
&=P\left(\left|-\frac{1}{n} \log \prod_{i=1}^{n} p\left(u_{i}\right)-H(U)\right| \leq \epsilon\right) \\
&=P\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}-\log p\left(u_{i}\right)\right]-H(U)\right| \leq \epsilon\right) \\
& \rightarrow 1 \text { as } n \rightarrow \infty
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: I've noticed that you have cross posted a couple of questions (e.g. [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46531/notation-of-sequences-in-rate-distortion-theory)). Note that this is strongly discouraged on the SE network, for reasons discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). Please avoid doing this in the future.

Comment: Will remember @stochasticboy321. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The way this proof is usually written, there is an abuse of notation [it may have been clarified elsewhere in the book]. When one writes

$$
P\left(U^{n} \in A_{\epsilon}^{(n)}\right) =P\left(\left|-\frac{1}{n} \log p\left(U^{n}\right)-H(U)\right|\right) \leq \epsilon
$$
this is shorthand for
$$
P\left(\left\{\omega: \left|-\frac{1}{n} \log p[(u_1,\ldots,u_n)(\omega)]-H(U)\right| \right\}\right) \leq \epsilon.
$$
where $\omega\in \Omega,$ the sample space. Maybe it is clearer if we suppress the dependence on $\omega$ and just write
$$
P\left(\left\{\omega: \left|-\frac{1}{n} \log p(u_1,\ldots,u_n)-H(U)\right| \right\}\right) \leq \epsilon.
$$