# Meaning of $p(X)$

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I have recently come across the notation $p(X)$ i.e [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621196/notation-in-proof-for-the-asymptotic-equipartition-property).
I have not seen this notation of mixing small $p$ and a random variable $X$ before. 
For instance lets assume we have a fair die such that $p(x) = 1/6$ for all $x$ in the sample space {1,2,3,4,5,6}. We draw a random variable $X \sim p(x)$. What would $p(X)$ denote in this case?

Answer (score 1):

$p$ either denotes the PMF or PDF of a distribution. It is a non-random function.

You can plug a random variable into a function to get a new random variable.

When discussing entropy in the context of information theory, one often plugs in a random variable $X$ into its own PDF/PMF $p$, yielding a new random variable $p(X)$.

Comment: So for the example in the questions p(X) is a random variable but the outcome is 1/6 always?

Comment: @sn3jd3r Yes. ${}$